# Showing that the sequence is Cauchy if $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Let $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<a_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then prove that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$.

We have for any $p=1,2,\cdots$ that $|x_{n+p}-x_n|\le a_n+a_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p-1}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n+p-1} a_k$. From here how can I show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy ?

Any hint please?

Comment: Your final upper bound $\sum_{k=1}^{n+p-1} a_k$ has a needlessly bad **lower** summation index

Comment: Same proof as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182830/proving-that-a-sequence-such-that-a-n1-a-n-le-2-n-is-cauchy?rq=1

Comment: This question in some form appears too often. Did you try to find a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: bound $a_n+\cdots+a_{n+p-1}\leq\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^na_n$.