# Alternate standard definition of convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Is this a standard definition of convergence of a sequence?

> $\{x_n\}$ converges if and only if for any given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$ $\forall$ $n > N$.

If you know, please mention if this definition exists in (baby) Rudin (or the likes of it).

Comment: It isn't the standard definition because the equivalence doesn't even hold when you use the standard definition of convergence on the left-hand side of the proposed implication. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2646883 for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a sequence is not even necessarily bounded. For example, look at $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. Then, $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=\frac{1}{n+1}$ which converges to $0$, so the condition you write is satisfied (what you wrote is the definition for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=0$ in the usual sense). However, as we all know, the partial sums of the harmonic series diverge: $x_n\to\infty$, so $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not convergent.

Of course, this isn’t special to the harmonic series. You can construct similar easy counterexamples by taking any positive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which vanishes as $n\to\infty$ but such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$. Then, let $x_n$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum.